# Return contents between two TR tags using Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I have been trying to scrape some data off a website. The source has differentiated all the headers of tables to that of the actual contents by different class names. Because I want to scrape all the table information, I got all the headers into one array and contents into another array. But the problem is that when I am trying to write the array contents into a file, I can write a header but second array contains contents from all the table and I cannot mark where contents of first table ends.
Because htmlagilitypack scrapes all the tags of specified Nodes, I get all the contents. First let me show the code to make it clear:

```html
<tr class=tableHeader>
<th width=16%>Caught</th>
<th width=16%><p><a href="/url">Normal Range</a></p></th>
</tr>
<TR class=content><TD><a href="/url"><i>Bluegill</i></a></TD>
<TD>trap net</TD>
<TD align=CENTER>4.05</TD>
<TD align=CENTER>    7.9 -    37.7</TD>
<TD align=CENTER>0.26</TD>
<TD align=CENTER>    0.1 -     0.2</TD>
</TR>
<TR class=content><TD><i></i></TD>
<TD>Gill net</TD>
<TD align=CENTER>1.50</TD>
<TD align=CENTER>N/A</TD>
<TD align=CENTER>0.07</TD>
<TD align=CENTER>N/A</TD>
</TR>
<tr class=tableHeader>
<th>0-5</th>
<th>6-8</th>
<th>9-11</th>
<th>12-14</th>
<th>15-19</th>
<th>20-24</th>
<th>25-29</th>
<th>30+</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr>
<TR class=content><TD><i>bluegill</i></TD>
<TD align=CENTER>19</TD>
<TD align=CENTER>65</TD>
<TD align=CENTER>0</TD>
<TD align=CENTER>0</TD>
<TD align=CENTER>0</TD>
<TD align=CENTER>0</TD>
<TD align=CENTER>0</TD>
<TD align=CENTER>0</TD>
<TD align=CENTER>84</TD>
</TR>
```

Below is my code to save the headers and contents into array and try to display it exactly like in the website.

```
int count =0;
foreach (var trTag4Pale in trTags4Pale)
{
    string trText4Pale = trTag4Pale.InnerText;
    paleLake[count] = trText4Pale;
    if (trTags4Small != null)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (var trTag4Small in trTags4Small)
        {
            string trText4Small = trTag4Small.InnerText;
            smallText[counter] = trText4Small;
            counter++;
        }
     }
     File.AppendAllText(path,paleLake[count]+Environment.Newline+smallText[count]+Environment.Newline);
}
```

As you see, When I try to append the contents of the array to a file, it lines in the first header, and contents of all the table. But I only want contents of the first table and would repeat the process to get the content of the second table and so forth.
If I could get the contents between  tr tag tableHeader, the arrays for the content would contain every contents for all the tables in different arrays. I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best approach but I made it work somehow. It might be useful resource for somebody someday. So below is the code that worked for me. I append the data stored in the list into an excel sheet. As I have all the data I need for each tr tag with each class, I can manipulate the data I want:

```
var trTags4Header = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='tableheader']");
if (trTags4Header != null)
{
    //Create a list to store td values 
    List<string> tableList1 = new List<string>();
    int row = 2;
    foreach (var item in trTags4Header)
    {
        //Get only next siblings which matches the calss name as "content" 
        var found = item.SelectNodes("followin-sibling::*").TakeWhile(tag => tag.Name == "tr" && tag.Attributes["class"].Value == "content");
        //store the nodes selected in an array (this is the selection of nodes I wanted which has td information I want. 
        HtmlNode[] nextItem = found.ToArray();
        foreach (var node in nextItem)
        {
            //Gets individual td values within tr class='content' Notice .//td- this starts looking from the present node instead of the root nodes.
            var tdValues = node.SelectNodes(".//td").TakeWhile(tdTag => tdTag.Name == "td");
            int column = 1;
            //Stores each td values into the list which is why I have control over the data to where I want to store, I am storing them in one excel worksheet.
            foreach (var tdText in tdValues)
            {
                tableList1.Add(tdText.InnerText);
                ws1.Cells[row, column] = tdText.InnerText;
                column++;
            }
            row++;
         }
     }
     //Display the content in a listbox 
     listBox1.DataSource = tableList1;
}
```

Please suggest a better solution if you come across this or leave your feedback. Thanks